# how to get a tomcat thread id that is processing a request based on jsessionid

Tags: java, tomcat

how to get a tomcat thread id that is processing a request based on jsessionid.

Assume below are the log statements generated while accessing the web application by an user through web browser. From the browser coockie i have access to jessionId, now is it possible to get the thread id that is printed in the below logs. http-8080-2

```
2014-12-11 15:44:11,302 [http-8080-2] [INFO] 
2014-12-11 15:44:11,305 [http-8080-2] [INFO] 
2014-12-11 15:44:11,305 [http-8080-2] [WARN] 
2014-12-11 15:44:11,309 [http-8080-2] [WARN]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: tomcat will not be using the same thread to handle traffic from a single user session. So for a single user session, the requests may be handled by multiple threads. So I dont think mapping jsessionid and threadid is not possible.

Comment: if my understanding is correct, the above statement is not valid. to confirm this I have started a user session pointing to my web application ex: https://123.com/, i noticed the below thread id in the logs http-8080-2 when i hit the home page url first time, thereafter i have accessed  couple of web pages and then closed the browser. Using the above thread i could tract all my activity in the log file that i have performed in that session period.

Comment: Subin - I did perform the above test, while a lot other current user's are accessing the web portal, still i am able to track all my activity based on jsession and threadid mapping